# WP_Query, сортировка по произвольным полям

Tags: php, wordpress

Допустим есть произвольный тип, созданный с помощью `register_post_type('custom_type'...)`
Такой запрос выведет все записи этого типа:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'custom_type',
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Но у этого типа записи есть произвольные поля, и нужно получить доступ к этим полям в массиве $query (поля из таблицы `wp_postmeta`), чтобы можно было их отсортировать во время построения разметки.
т.е. чтобы не делать несколько запросов в базу данных, делая выборку с помощью `meta_query`, как можно сделать один запрос, и потом выводить записи, в зависимости от произвольного поля?
По умолчанию этот запрос `$query = new WP_Query( $args );` выводит только данные из таблицы `wp_post`. А нужно ещё прикрепить к этому массиву данные из таблицы `wp_postmeta`.
Как это сделать?

**P.S.**

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'custom_post',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'some_key',
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

этот код не добавляет данные в массив $query

**P.S.**

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'custom_post',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'some_key',
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if( $query->have_posts() ){
while( $query->have_posts() ){
    $query->the_post();
    if(isset($query['price']){
    ...
    }
    if(isset($query['wired']){
    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_query#meta_query

Comment: @KAGG Design, meta_query не добавляет данные в массив $query.

Comment: Это значит, что вы его направильно используете, больше ничего.

Comment: У вас где в вашем коде value или EXISTS/NOT EXISTS? Вы почитайте внимательно, что на kama написано

Comment: И в вопросе у вас смешались кони, люди. Данные из postmeta никак нельзя запихнуть в $query. Но в то же время вы говорите про выборку по произвольным полям. Для выборки нужен meta_query, для вывода поля из поста в $query - нужна `get_post_meta()`

Comment: @KAGG Design, так можно запихнуть данные из таблицы `wp_postmeta` в массив `$query`? Для чего в массиве meta_query указывать value и exists, если мне нужны все записи? И уже после выборки из базы данных всех записей, нужно допустим вывести сначала те записи, у которых есть произвольное поле `price`, потом ниже вывести записи, у которых есть произвольное поле `wired`

Comment: добавил в вопрос код

Comment: Вот опять вы невнимательно читаете. Я же вам написал: "Данные из postmeta никак нельзя запихнуть в $query." Я вам написал также "поля из ПОСТА в $query - нужна get_post_meta()". Не из массива, а из ПОСТА. Вы получаете ПОСТ из массива query, узнаете его id, и вызываете `get_post_meta()`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91810/discussion-between-kagg-design-and-word).